# CSS issue in Sencha/extjs 2.3

Tags: html, css

When we scroll the fields on UI for going the last column, the CSS is breaking down and also tried to use the custom CSS, but when we use it at that time, the last field has been disappearing. This has been happening from last one month, not sure because of the updated chrome(100.0.4896.127) and also tried in Edge(101.0.1210.32)as well and don't know the issue is related to sencha/extjs 2.3 or browser related issue. Any suggestion/Help will be really helpful.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tycK8.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the .x-grid3-row css and
Add the display: inline-table; property in your custom css file. Then it should work fine.

```
.x-grid3-row {
cursor: default;
border: 1px solid #ededed;
border-top-color: #fff;
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
}
```